# Unable to make loop work - VBSCRIPT

Tags: loops, for-loop, foreach, vbscript, while-loop

I am trying to create a loop in vbscript that does 10x something (in this case, sending a keystroke every 5min to the computer. I tried several loop types, but I can't figure out how to make it work, I just get error 800A0005 at launch.

What can I do?

### Here is the code:

```
Set Ws = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
Dim cpt
cpt = 0
For cpt = 0 to 10 step 1
    ws.Sendkeys "{Ctrl}"
    Pause(5) 'Pause de 5 minutes
Next

Function Pause(NbMin)
wscript.Sleep(60000*NbMin)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code for sending the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> Key is `^`.

So, try replacing

```
ws.Sendkeys "{Ctrl}"
```

with

```
ws.Sendkeys "^"
```

See this [LINK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send(v=vs.110).aspx) for more information.